# Partitions for a programmer computer

Tags: ubuntu, partition

I have a laptop with Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS as an OS and 130 GB SSD and 1 TB HDD storage. I'm looking for partitions to speed up my laptop efficiently. I mainly use my laptop to program stuff in Python and C++ (visual computing) and additonally, some word processing and internet surfing. More systematically, I guess my stuff can be categorized as follows:

- IDEs
- Compiled libraries
- Other low level programming utilties
- Programming projects
- Docker
- data such as images or dataframes
- pdf and libreoffice files
- internet browser

**How should I organize the partitions of my laptop?**

I thought of the following

Partitions on SDD

1. Booting
2. Actively used compiled libraries, programming projects, IDE and Docker
3. Actively used data

Partitions on HDD

1. /home with pdf and libreoffice files
2. Other applications not required to run fast, e.g. libreoffice and firefox
3. Not actively used libraries and data

**Does this partitioning make sense?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm looking for partitions to speed up my laptop efficiently.

Partitions don't make anything faster, in themselves.

Aside from the inevitable partitions needed to boot, there's no reason whatsoever to use partitions to manage your data – they are an unnecessarily rigid complication on what you actually want to achieve: Store some data on your SSD and your Hard drive, in a way that reflects your use case.

> Does this partitioning make sense?

No, sadly.

Your use case describes three kinds of data:

1. Data necessary for booting
2. Data that needs to be accessed fast and frequently
3. Data that needs to be accessed infrequently

Generally, you can't well tell which system libaries belong in group 2 or 3 just based on their location – your compiler and all the libraries you use are in exactly the same places as the programs and libraries you use infrequently.

Thus, no partitioning/volume management scheme **can** help you with this!

First off: I don't know your budget. But: a 1 TB SATA SSD costs you about 50 {€,$} ([SATA](https://www.heise.de/preisvergleich/patriot-p210-1tb-p210s1tb25-a2325300.html?v=k&hloc=de), much faster M.2/NVMe SSDs run roughly the same price, typically), 512 GB can be had for 25€. So maybe this issue is actually better solved by throwing money at the problem and replacing your SSD by a larger one, and reducing your HDD to storage for cat pictures; or by replacing your HDD with another SSD and using both SSDs with LVM as one large SSD with striping (do *not* forget to do backups regularly). 
Hard drives and laptops are kind of a rare combination these days – both for power and for reliability reasons, not even considering the speed aspect.

Now, if your SSD is already a rather fast one (compared to the speeds of the hard drive), and you have no budget to buy another SSD:

You would want to set up your SSD to become a *cache* in front of your slower but larger HDD. Linux can do that, out of the box: `bcache` is the mechanism with which you can use a fast block device (e.g., the last one of the four partitions on your SSD, the first still being `/boot/efi`'s vfat/uefisys, the second classically being /boot and the third being SWAP/hibernation data, which you definitely want on a laptop) to "buffer" away the data about to be written to the slower HDD, and to keep frequently read data around, so that it doesn't have to be loaded from HDD every time.

The idea is that instead of in which directory something lies (/home, /usr/lib, /home/oldprojects or something), you let the system *detect and manage itself* which data are needed frequently.

And then, on the thus "sped up" block device, you would **not** do partitions (there's no reasons for partitions), you would just set up an LVM physical volume, with an LVM volume group on it. You could just as well just have a single partition on that, for all your data (except for /boot), as putting things into different filesystem is mostly useful for block device backup purposes, and not measurably advantageous for speed these days. However, making the (cached) system an LVM physical volume means a lot more flexibility, at no performance cost. I strongly recommend it, universally. You will not miss not having to deal with partitions any more :)

So, in similarity to the scheme proposed in this guide, *[Installing Ubuntu 20.04 with bcache support](https://kloppenborg.net/blog/installing-ubuntu-20-04-with-bcache/)* ([snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20221206110256/https://kloppenborg.net/blog/installing-ubuntu-20-04-with-bcache/):

- Let the SSD be `/dev/ssd`, with partitions `/dev/ssd1, ssd2, …, ssdN`
- Let the HDD be `/dev/hdd`
- SSD:

  - `/dev/ssd1`: `/boot/efi`, VFAT, 1GB for UEFI (plenty large for that
  - `/dev/ssd2`: `/boot`, ext4, 4GB for never-worry-about-this-again
  - `/dev/ssd3`: swap partition, swap, 2× RAM size, for hibernation
  - `/dev/ssd4`: cache for `/dev/bcache0`, occupying the rest of your SSD
- HDD

  - `/dev/hdd1`: backing storage for `/dev/bcache0`, whole disk
- `/dev/bcache0`: LVM physical volume (only one in new Volume Group, let's call it `vg0`
- `/vg0`: LVM volume group containing all your data

  - `/dev/vg0/root`: System volume for `/`; ext4 or XFS (or whatever you like), whatever you need GB (can trivially be grown while system is running later on, can be as large as the whole hard drive)

That seems a bit convoluted, but it's really just that you need to go through the `bcache` layer to get to use your SSD partition as cache for what you store on the hard drive, and the LVM volume group is just there to not shoot you in the foot later on or during backups or when you replace your failing HDD.

The guide linked above says (and I believe that still to be true) that Ubuntu needs to be tricked a bit during installation so that it includes the support for `bcache` in its boot image. But it really seems to be rather benign.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer.